# Interline Plating Carriers - Whose baggage policy applies?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, code-share, fare-class

I learned about Interline Partnerships and Plating Carriers today and I am wondering how these agreements work in regards to baggage policy. In particular, I'm curious as to whose baggage fees are applied.

For instance, say I bought a ticket which flew:

- First Segment: Ottawa to Montreal with Air Canada.
- Second Segment: Montreal to Paris with Air France.
- Return flight is the reverse of the outbound itinerary (CDG -> YUL -> YOW)
- Air Canada is the Plating Carrier
- No baggage allowance provided with this ticket

When I check-in at the Ottawa airport with some baggage to be checked, will I be charged Air Canada's rates? Or will I have to pay baggage fees for both the Air Canada and Air France portions of the trip?

When I am returning and check-in at Charles De Gaulle with the same baggage, do I pay Air France's baggage fees or will Air Canada's status as the Plating Carrier still determine my baggage fees?

Answer (score 2):

If the itinerary is booked on one ticket (its a code-share), then the Most Significant Carrier rule (from IATA) applies.

Air Canada has a [pdf on their website](https://www.aircanada.com/content/dam/aircanada/portal/documents/PDF/en/International_Tariff_en.pdf) that details rules and conditions of carriage, here are the relevant bits:

> In the case of code-share, the baggage rules of the first marketing
>   carrier (carrier whose code appears on the flight number) may apply,
>   not those of the operating carrier.

Not really much to say there, Qatar Airways has [more details](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-kw/partners-codeshare/most-significant-carrier.html):

> The Most Significant Marketing Carrier (MSC) is:
>
> - For travel between IATA areas: The first carrier flying in between two of the IATA areas
> - For travel between IATA sub areas: The first carrier flying in between the sub areas
> - For travel within an IATA sub area: The first carrier crossing an international border

For your flight from Canada to France (and return) you are crossing IATA areas. So the baggage rules of Air France will apply.